# Java Parallel Stream Produce HashMap

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following test, test the integers ranging from 0 to max and if it is validated, construct the pair (vals[i], i). Finally, I want to produce a HashMap which uses vals[i] as key and the value is the list of integers. The code looks like,

```
IntStream.range(0, max)
   .parallel()
   .filter(i-> sometest(i))
   .mapToObj(i -> new Pair<>(vals[i],i))
   .collect(groupingBy(Pair::getFirst, mapping(Pair::getSecond, toList())));
```

My question is, is it possible to use parallel streams to speed up the construction of that map?

Thanks.

Comment: Speed up depends on various factor of your application, What is the usual `max` in your app ? is `sometest(i)` CPU intensive ? how is the CPU utilization on your app in normal environment ? how many threads you app spawns up usually ? (You don't have to answer these, just giving you factors to think about)

can you also try benchmarking with parallel and without parallel ?

Comment: Have you considered a reduce function using a map as the accumulator?

Comment: Your code is already using a parallel stream. So what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

If you just wanted to know how to better take advantage of parallelism, you could do something like:

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, List<Integer>> map = IntStream.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    .parallel()
    .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(
        i -> i / 3,
        Collectors.mapping(i -> i, Collectors.toList())));
```

The intermediate creation of Pairs is unnecessary, and `groupingByConcurrent` accumulates to the new ConcurrentMap in parallel.

Keep in mind that with parallel stream you are stuck with the common `ForkJoinPool`. For parallelization it's preferable to use something more flexible like an `ExecutorService` instead of Java Streams.

Answer (score 1):

These are the conditions you must satisfy so that you can perform a Concurrent Reduction, as stated in the [Java Documentation about Parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html#concurrent_reduction):

> The Java runtime performs a concurrent reduction if all of the the
>   following are true for a particular pipeline that contains the collect
>   operation:
>
> - The stream is parallel.
> - The parameter of the collect operation, the collector, has the characteristic Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT. To determine the
>     characteristics of a collector, invoke the Collector.characteristics
>     method.
> - Either the stream is unordered, or the collector has the characteristic Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED. To ensure that the
>     stream is unordered, invoke the BaseStream.unordered operation.

But whether it will speed up your the construction of your Map will depend on others aspects, as mentioned by @Jigar Joshi, including (but not only) :

- How many elements you have to process
- How many threads are already being used by your application

Sometimes the overhead of using parallelism (creating and stopping threads, making them communicate and synchronize, ...) is bigger than the gains.